# ABP.IO How do I integrate Stripe payment gateway with Angular UI?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, abp

We are using commercial version of ABP.IO with project generated using the ABP Suite using the following components

- Application template
- Angular
- Lepton-X
- EF
- SQLServer

Though we were able to run the Stripe payment integration using MVC as UI, we are facing hard time in implementing the same with Angular as UI.

We found the package https://abp.io/package-detail/@volo_abp.ng.payment yet there is no concrete examples available officially or in the web on how to use it.

If someone can help us with end to end example on how to integrate Stripe in ABP.IO using Angular as UI layer, it will really helpful as we are in unable to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unofficial [stripe-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe-angular) package that can help you on the frontend. Alternatively, you can use the official plain JavaScript package: [stripe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-js). It's important to use the Stripe SDK on the frontend so you don't want to worry about [PCI-compliance](https://stripe.com/gb/guides/pci-compliance).

I don't know of any wrapper libraries for your backend, but you can just send raw HTTP requests to Stripe API: [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl). Use of SDK is not required on the backend as no credit card data passes through your app.